# my last ouyput keeps on looping after trying break staement also it continues here is my code in python3

Tags: python

```
import array
import statistics as st
a = int(input())
x = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
t = sum(x)
n = len(x)
print(t/n)
mv = st.median(x)
print(mv)
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(x)):
        if(x[i] == x[j]):
            print(x[j]);
            break
        else:
            print(min(x))
            break
```

output:

43900.6
44627.5
4978
4978
4978
4978
4978
4978
4978
4978
4978

Expected Output:

43900.6
44627.5
4978

Comment: Could you give an example input ? Also, it seems like your `a` variable is unused.

Comment: Yo may need to consider using boolean inside the second for loop and breaking the parent loop by using the boolean obtained in the nested one. By the way there is no need for second for loop because you break it in the first iteration anyway. Your code always prints output `n-1` times where n is your input length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those break statements are only exiting the inner loop.
You have to add another break statement to exit the outer loop.

```
import array
import statistics as st
a = int(input())
x = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
t = sum(x)
n = len(x)
print(t/n)
mv = st.median(x)
print(mv)
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(x)):
        if(x[i] == x[j]):
            print(x[j]);
            break
        else:
            print(min(x))
            break
    break
```

Now when it exits the inner for, it goes to the outer one which will also exit.